# Compile and execute java source code without knowing where the Main method is?

Tags: java, compilation

I am facing the following problem:

I will receive one or more .java files. The idea is to automate the compile and execute process.

1. I have not written nor viewed .java source files i receive.
2. There may be 1 file or multiple files in multiple directories.
3. All of this is done under linux ( Debian / CentOS ).

Here is an example case:

- 2 files are received:
- SomeFile.java and SomeOtherFile.Java ( This one has the **static public void main(String args[]){}** method but **i do NOT know that !**)
- A process picks up the files and compiles them in this way: 
  **javac -encoding UTF-8 -sourcepath . -d . *.java**

**So my problem is:** I do not know which package(if any) contains the Main method so i do not know what do execute ?

```
java packageName.SomeOtherFile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plenty of ways:

1. Get [a java source code parser](https://github.com/matozoid/javaparser), parse the source code, find the method
2. Compile everything, go over the resulting *.class files using reflection, find the method.
3. For a small enough number of files, just try them all

Comment: ... i ended up just looking @ all the files, and finding out where the package and Main functions are ...

Answer (score 1):

I have written something like this before:

```
package vonbulow.nicki;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

/**
 *
 * @author Nicki
 */
public class AppLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private static final String userdir = System.getenv("USERPROFILE");
    private static final AppLoader instance = new AppLoader();

    private static HashMap<String, Class> loaded = new HashMap<String, Class>();

    public static void loadapp(final String name) {

        if(loaded.containsKey(name)) {
            Thread d = new Thread(new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    try {
                        Class c = loaded.get(name);
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
                        m.invoke(null, (Object[])new String[]{null});
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {

                    }
                }
            });
            d.start();
            return;
        }

        File ud = new File(userdir+"\\nvbapp");
        ud.mkdir();
        File[] fa = ud.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".appn");
            }
        });

        for(final File f:fa) {
            if(f.getName().split("\\.")[0].equalsIgnoreCase(name)) {
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        runapp(f, name);
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void runapp(File f, String nam) {

        List<Class> classes = new ArrayList<Class>();
        ZipFile jf;
        String name = "";
        try {
            jf = new ZipFile(f);
            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> eze = jf.entries();
            while(eze.hasMoreElements()){
                ZipEntry ze = eze.nextElement();
                if(ze.getName().endsWith(".class")&&!ze.isDirectory()){
                    InputStream fis = jf.getInputStream(ze);
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)ze.getSize()];
                    fis.read(bytes);
                    classes.add(instance.defineClass(getClassName(bytes), bytes, 0, bytes.length));
                }
                if(ze.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")) {
                    Manifest manifest = new Manifest(jf.getInputStream(ze));
                    name = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Main-Class");
                }
            }
            Iterator<Class> classit = classes.iterator();
            while(classit.hasNext()) {
                Class c = classit.next();
                if(c.getName().equals(name)) {
                    try {
                        loaded.put(nam, c);
                        Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("main", String[].class);
                        m.invoke(null, (Object[]) new String[]{null});
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AppLoader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private static String getClassName(byte[] is) {
        try {
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(is));
            dis.readLong(); // skip header and class version
            int cpcnt = (dis.readShort()&0xffff)-1;
            int[] classes = new int[cpcnt];
            String[] strings = new String[cpcnt];
            for(int i=0; i<cpcnt; i++) {
                int t = dis.read();
                if(t==7) classes[i] = dis.readShort()&0xffff;
                else if(t==1) strings[i] = dis.readUTF();
                else if(t==5 || t==6) { dis.readLong(); i++; }
                else if(t==8) dis.readShort();
                else dis.readInt();
            }
            dis.readShort(); // skip access flags
            return strings[classes[(dis.readShort()&0xffff)-1]-1].replace("/", ".");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

I have not edited it; you will need to edit it so it loads your own classes.
You also need to compile the files first with the [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) class. This also assumes that the classes are in the zip file.